# Keep a page locked to a specific aspect ratio

Tags: css, html

I was designing a webpage for a Spanish project and I had a problem. When you changed the size of the screen everything would get squished. I know you can set a min width to create a horizontal scroll bar when it reaches a certain pixel width but I wanted to know how to make the page resize like an image does.

It would keep a certain aspect ratio and just get smaller as you decrease the size. Here is a link to my html for the home page (the images in it won't work because they are local to my computer)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4X_NejFwvp7dmVqX091SU5fTUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please read this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To easily implement mobile browsing on your site I strongly recommend you look into bootstrap, using the columns they provide.  To do it yourself you need to work with %'s, @media queries, vh / vw etc.